# Math округление в java

Tags: java, математика

Функция в java Math.ceil() должна округлять число при делении в большую сторону, т.е. вправо 
Так при делении 12/5 = 2.4, тогда Math.ceil(12/5) = 3;
но:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Math.ceil(12/5));
    }
```

Выводит мне 2.0 , Math.floor(12/5) тоже выводит 2.0 Может я не правильно понимаю, как они работают?

Comment: Намек: напишите `12.0/5.0` и посмотрите, что получится.

Comment: Всё, понял, спасибо     )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для удобства любого округления лучше всего использовать класс `BigDecimal`:

```
new BigDecimal(12.0/5).setScale(0, RoundingMode.CEILING).doubleValue();
```

Первый параметр указывает до какого знака округление, а второй - правило округления.

Answer (score 5):

Дело в том, что `12/5` - само по себе целочисленное деление, результат уже равен `2`.

`Math.ceil(12.0/5) == 3.0`

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в том, что в java нет таких специальных операторов как `div` или `mod` как в Pascal. Потому, знак / работает как целочисленное деление 12/5 действительно равно 2 (и остаток 2). Именно потому, если мы хотим получить дробь, нам нужно кастонуть целочисленный делитель и делимое к float. А сделать это можно как угодно. Хоть `12f/5f`, хоть `(float)a/(float)b`. И только после этого уже можно производить округления и пр.